# Using razor engine to parse cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I have two apps. One of them is web app and the other one is mobile app. I am trying to parse one of the views from the web app and compile a html file for the mobile app. The structure of my view in web app is as follows

1. App.cshtml

   - partialview1.cshtml
   - partialview2.cshtml
   - ....

The web app is built in asp.net mvc and I am using Microsoft visual studio cordova to built the mobile apps.

I have a separate project, which takes the App.cshtml and compile index.html for mobile app. Here is the structure of my App.cshtml file

```
@model Account
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
ViewBag.Title = Texts.App;
}

@section head{
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/app")
}

@section scripts {

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tippnett/app")

<script>
    var userId = '@Model.Id';
    TippNett.StartApp();

</script>

}
<div id="appview" class="loading">
<div id="workspace" class="map_canvas">
    <section class="other-stuff">
        @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/subPagesForApp/_locationWindow.cshtml")
        @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/subPagesForApp/_moveLocationWindow.cshtml")
        @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/subPagesForApp/_orderWindow.cshtml")
        @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/subPagesForApp/_createLocation.cshtml")
        @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/subPagesForApp/_ordersListWindow.cshtml")
        @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/subPagesForApp/_reportAbuse.cshtml")
    </section>
</div>

<div class="locations-list" data-bind="visible:locationView">
    @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/subPagesForApp/_locationList.cshtml")
</div>

<div id="loading-wale">
    <div id="loading-info">
        <div>
            <i class="spinner">&nbsp;</i>
        </div>
        <div>@Texts.Loading</div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="show-for-small" id="stick-menu" data-role="footer">
<div class="icon-bar three-up ">
    <a class="item active locations" data-bind="click: openLocationView.bind($data,true)">
        <i class="fi-marker"></i>
        <label>@Texts.Location</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item maps" data-bind="click: openMapView.bind($data,true)">
        <i class="fi-map"></i>
        <label>@Texts.Maps</label>
    </a>
    <a class="item notifications" data-bind="click: openOrders.bind($data,true)">
        <i class="fi-list"></i>
        <span class="order-notification-counter notification-counter" data-bind=" text: orders().length,visible: orders().length > 0"></span>
        <span class="matches-notification-counter notification-counter" data-bind=" text: matches().length,visible: matches().length > 0"></span>
        <label>
            @Texts.OrdersLabel
        </label>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have looked into **RazorEngine.Razor.Compile**, but no luck. I have also looked into this library as well http://razorengine.codeplex.com/, but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "no luck"? Also the latest version can be found here https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine as the project moved to github.

Comment: I have made a custom template for html stuff. I have been able to cater html.raw and pagerender stuff, but I am struggling with html.partial function. Can you provide an example of catering that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cshtml is run server side,cordova app run in mobile(client)
so i think you can't run mvc on mobile,you should use some mobile framework
html as template,js call ajax get data,and bind to html template.

Comment: I am not running mvc on mobile, I just want to parse the html and use it in my mobile app.

Comment: you can send a ajax request to some url,this url will return html.then put it to your cordova html page's body tag.but there are some more question.the link,pic will go out your app